# Append items to / from list using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I change the function so that instead of adding the item to the list and removing the item from that list, I can just use checkboxes to add/remove items from either the initial item OR the appended item in the list?

The UX should mimic a wishlist where items are added/removed from the wishlist by checking the item's checkbox.

```js
// Wish Function
var wish = {
  items: []
};
var update_product = function(product) {};
$(function() {
  //Add to wish
  var addToWish = function(product, qty) {
    qty = qty || 1;
    var wish = getWish();
    var indexOfId = wish.items.findIndex(x => x.id == product.id);
    if (indexOfId === -1) {
      wish.items.push({
        id: product.id,
        img: product.img,
        name: product.name,
      });
      $parent = $("#" + product.id).closest(".items__wish");
      $parent
        .find(".wish-icon")
        .addClass("active")
        .attr("data-prefix", "fas");
    } else {
      wish.items[indexOfId].qty++;
      wish.items[indexOfId].stock = Number(product.stock);
    }
    //Update popup wish
    updateWish(wish);
  };

  var getProductValues = function(element) {
    var productId = $(element)
      .closest(".items__wish")
      .find(".item__tile")
      .attr("id");
    var productImg = $(element)
      .closest(".items__wish")
      .find(".item__img")
      .attr("src");
    var productName = $(element)
      .closest(".items__wish")
      .find(".item__title")
      .html();
    return {
      id: productId,
      img: productImg,
      name: productName,
    };
  };
  $(".my-wish-add").on("change", function() {
    var product = getProductValues(this);
    addToWish({
      id: product.id,
      img: product.img,
      name: product.name,
    });
  });
  //Update wish html to reflect changes
  var updateWish = function(wish) {
    //Add to shopping wish dropdown
    $(".wishlist__items").html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < wish.items.length; i++) {
      $(".wishlist__items").append(
        "<li>" +
        '<div class="my-wish-item">' +
        "<img src='" +
        wish.items[i].img +
        "' />" +
        '<div class="wish-main">' +
        '<div class="wish-name">' +
        wish.items[i].name +
        "</div>" +
        '<div class="my-wish-remove-container">' +
        '<input type="checkbox" id="my-wish-remove' +
        i +
        '" class="my-wish-remove" aria-hidden="true">' +
        "<i class='fas fa-heart'></i>" +
        "</div>"
      );
      //Remove from wish on id
      var removeFromWish = function(id) {
        var wish = getWish();
        var wishIndex = wish.items.findIndex(x => x.id == id);
        wish.items.splice(wishIndex, 1);
        $parent = $("#" + id).closest(".items__wish");
        $parent
          .find(".wish-icon")
          .first()
          .removeClass("active")
          .attr("data-prefix", "far");
        //Update popup wish
        updateWish(wish);
      };
      (function() {
        var currentIndex = i;
        $("#my-wish-remove" + currentIndex).on("change", function() {
          $(this)
            .closest("li")
            .hide(400);
          setTimeout(function() {
            wish.items[currentIndex].stock = "";
            update_product(wish.items[currentIndex]);
            removeFromWish(wish.items[currentIndex].id);
          }, 400);
        });
      })();
    }
  };
  //Get Wish
  var getWish = function() {
    var myWish = wish;
    return myWish;
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Pro";
  font-weight: 900;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
}

.wishlist__list {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.wishlist__items li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="wishlist">
  <div class="wishlist__list">
    <ul class="wishlist__items">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='products'>
  <div class="items__wish">
    <div id='1' class='item__title item__tile'>Product 1</div>
    <img class="item__img" src="https://www.iconasys.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/360-Product-Photography-White-Background-Acrylic-Riser-08.jpg">
    <label class="wish-btn">
    <input type="checkbox" name="wish-check" class='my-wish-add'><i class="wish-icon far fa-heart"></i></input></label>
  </div>
  <div class="items__wish">
    <div id='2' class='item__title item__tile'>Product 2</div>
    <img class="item__img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQoqpSgkG4AQDQOe33jI1NiW3GW2JSB-_v36aREsVyFQH55JFOJ">
    <label class="wish-btn">
    <input type="checkbox" name="wish-check" class='my-wish-add'><i class="wish-icon far fa-heart"></i></input></label>
```

Comment: you can manage selected item with array something. so when the checkbox is clicked, update the selected item.

Comment: Are you able to provide an answer with a snippet Chase Choi?

Comment: what about to trigger click wished lists' checkbox?

Comment: Can you please provide a working example?

Comment: to give you the example, I better write the whole things from zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - append changes using checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841572/jquery-append-changes-using-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that is add/remove wish item from item checkbox.
but it doesn't include the functionality on checkbox of wishlist, so you just refer this code to implement what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/s3n7ku6v/1/

```
var $wishlist__items = $(".wishlist__items");
var $myWishAdd = $(".my-wish-add");

$myWishAdd.on("click", function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target).parents(".items__wish");

  if (!$(e.target).is(":checked")) {
    removeFromWishList($target);
  } else {
    addToWishList($target);
  }
});

var addToWishList = function($target) {
  var img = $target.find('.item__img').attr('src');
  var $item__title = $target.find('.item__title');
  var id = $item__title.attr('id');
  var name = $item__title.text();

  $(".wishlist__items").append(
    "<li>" +
    '<div class="my-wish-item">' +
    "<img src='" +
    img +
    "' />" +
    '<div class="wish-main">' +
    '<div class="wish-name">' +
    name +
    "</div>" +
    '<div class="my-wish-remove-container">' +
    '<input type="checkbox" id="my-wish-remove' +
    id +
    '" class="my-wish-remove" aria-hidden="true">' +
    "<i class='fas fa-heart'></i>" +
    "</div>"
  );
}

var removeFromWishList = function($target) {
  var id = $target.find(".item__title").attr('id');

  $wishlist__items.find("#my-wish-remove" + id).parents("li").remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's half way there but the checkbox on the wishlist items need to be somehow linked to the original item's checkbox so the items can be removed from the list from either checkbox

Comment: You already have that function so you can edit your code refer to this code or edit this code refer to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your code a bit. This should give you an idea how to do it.

```js
$(".wish-add").on("change", function() {
  if ($(".wishlist .product[data-id=" + $(this).parent().attr("data-id") + "]").length){
    $(".wishlist .product[data-id=" + $(this).parent().attr("data-id") + "]").remove();
  }else{
    $(".wishlist").append($(this).parent()[0].outerHTML);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Pro";
  font-weight: 900;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
}

.wishlist {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wishlist">
    </div>
        
    <div class='products'>
      <div class="product" data-id="1">
        <div>Product 1</div>
        <img src="https://www.iconasys.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/360-Product-Photography-White-Background-Acrylic-Riser-08.jpg">
        <input type="checkbox" class='wish-add'>
        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
      </div>
  
      <div class="product" data-id="2">
        <div>Product 2</div>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQoqpSgkG4AQDQOe33jI1NiW3GW2JSB-_v36aREsVyFQH55JFOJ">     
        <input type="checkbox" class='wish-add'>
        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can you remove the wishlist item using it's checkbox also?

Comment: If it is already there, it will get removed from the DOM. Look at the jquery code.